# Disproportionate image subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, resize, subplot

I have been looking at a lot of threads on stack overflow about plot two differently sized images. But all of these posts refer to plots that still end up as either rectangles or squares like the example below.

[image]

Is it possible to have a set of subplots that are not equal in length or height? Something along the lines of this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the [`add_axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) function:

By default there is a canvas with a range 0 to 1 in x and y dimensions. `add_axes` adds and axis onto this, accepting a rectangle `[left,bottom,width,height]`. E.g.:

```
f=plt.gcf()
f.add_axes([0.1,0.8,0.1,0.1],axisbg='g')
f.add_axes([0.25,0.1,0.45,0.8],axisbg='r')
f.add_axes([0.8,0.4,0.15,0.5],axisbg='y')
f.add_axes([0.9,0.2,0.05,0.05],axisbg='b')
f.set_size_inches(10,6)
f.savefig('yourfig.png')
```

[image]